# Should I keep a state only in parent component or should I share it between parent and child components? React.js

Tags: reactjs

Let's assume I have a parent `App` component, which keeps user settings saved in it's state and synced throughout my app, by being passed down as a `Settings` object to all of it's children.

And for sake of the argument, Let's assume `App` has two other child components, one called `Settings` component, which holds a form, where the user inputs his/her settings and clicks submit to submit it's settings.

And another `Foo` component which projects/shows/hides various elements or other components based on the settings the user selected for the app in the earlier form.

Those two components won't render together, only once the user submits the form the `Foo` component is displayed.

Now I find myself tangled between two approaches: one, is to keep all settings also in a state saved inside my `Settings` component, and each time an input changes, update only the `Settings`'s component state accordingly, by having an handler for each input, and pass all those settings to the `App` component via a callback (which will update `App`'s state) only once the user submits the form.

Or, make `Settings` a stateless component, and pass all input handlers as callbacks (or as one unified callback) to the `App` component, which will then update the state on every input change.

As an old-school web developer, I prefer the first approach as it updated the `App` component only once, and so it re-renders all of it child components also only once, and yet my `Settings` component remains independent to the `App` component, and their only interface is the `OnSubmit` callback which passes the whole settings object once.

The second approach, on the other hand, separates all logic and handling from the `Settings` component, removes redundant states, and leaves it as a plain and simple UI "view" component if you will. And looks like the common design pattern used in many React apps I've seen.

Which approach is better and why? Is there anything else I'm missing out? How would you go by handling this? What is the best practice for parent-child interactions in React? How much would you want your child component to be encapsulated and independent from it's environment? And how many callbacks would you want to pass along from parent to child?

I would also really appreciate some good references and reading materials..

Thanks.

Comment: Redux is your solution. Although its definitely going to take some learning on your part.

Comment: Thanks I do agree, like other suggested, that redux or mobx or flux pattern approach might terminate the need in callbacks. But I feel like it's a harsh overkill for a simple problem, redux and others, as far as I know are needed where you have a lot of data flowing around. The problem I've described here is rather simple - it has a very simple form, and an object generated from it, that only flows once from one single child, to the parent , and then has to flow down from the parent to all of it's children, so hocking it up with data stores sounds somewhat exaggerated don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

State at top level component and stateless child components is always preferred in React.

Regarding callbacks, passing the 'relevant' ones down is again preferred. What is many very subjective. But readability must be the top most and 'callback' relevance to the child component.

In our large codebase, we have only 3 callbacks maximum and not more than 2 levels of nesting from the top most component. We have extensively used ES6 destructuring, Immutability Helpers, triple dot ... operator to manage the state at the top component (on receiving data from children) and keep all the children as stateless components.

This has helped us in improving tests and have a high coverage on the components as well. Easier to read and better performing components are definite results from stateless components.

If you have components that need 'events' to be passed down and not state (data), or if your nested levels are going beyond 2 and code is unmanageable then you have to explore state management frameworks like Redux (ex.,).

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good rule of thumb. Do you know if the stateless-child-components approach is solely for readability or might there be also a preference concern? Do you have any sources to support these claims?

Comment: React 16 (fiber) is understood to be having marginal perf improvements (Ref: Twitter thread https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/755343749983657986 by Dan Abramov.

please refer to 'Stateless functional components' section that mentioned about 'to be made perf improvements' in the past 
https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html#stateless-function-components.

Comment: @Sri can you point out to actual perf improvement for this in Fiber? Bet you can't, it is something that will be in the future, not in React 16 (sift through official changelog for example https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html)

Comment: @AndyTheos Marginal improvement is what i can notice in the tweet by Dan (which i have cited above already). There is no official release note in 16 and hence i mentioned 'understood to have'.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, and you need to provide at least a MVP to get some practical answers on this.
You can't go wrong with official documentation:

[Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

[Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll sure take a look at the links... I intentionally didn't want to add any code to the question, since it would probably result in a lot of code, that will drift away from the question itself to practical solutions, while I wanted to keep it as an abstract argument on which approach will lead to a better design.

I'll try to work out some basic examples maybe..

Comment: Yeah, exactly, i was asking you to try and tackle this question with basic example, maybe with naive realisation of App->[Settings, Foo] you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [flux pattern](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html), You can put your state into data stores and allows components to share data and also watch for changes, this will avoid an explosion of handlers and props cascading down the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think this might be an overkill for a basic and simple app, right? assuming I want to keep using react's original single direction data-flow without additions, and assuming the only data cascading to components is the `Settings` object, I think building a data store to save it is somewhat over-engineering.....?

Just to clearly, the question is, what approach will be better, and why? -  updating the parent once with all of the data, and yet keeping it in a state for the child, or, contentiously updating the parent from the child.